# Map defined if value not in dictionary - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I'm busy with the Titanic kaggle and I want to simplify and Pythonify this piece of code:

```
allData = [trainData, testData]

commonTitles = {'Mlle' : 'Miss', 'Ms' : 'Miss', 'Mme' : 'Mrs', all others : 'Rare'}

for dataset in allData:
dataset['Title'].map(commonTitles)
```

How do I specify the *all others* part?
Also, will the map command skip 'Miss' and 'Mrs' here or will it change them to 'Rare'?

Thank you

Comment: have you tried to run this? that's not even valid python

Comment: first read this https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries and understand it then try to refactor someones code.

Comment: You should state if you're trying to port from another language or else pseudocode - some people are criticizing or downvoting because this isn't legal Python.

Comment: But the code, as edited aka () instead of {}, is Python code. It was a simple typo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First change dictionary by remove `Rare` and add 2 elements with same key and value for avoid replace them to `Rare`, add [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for replace no match values and because loop list of DataFrame create another one:

```
commonTitles = {'Mlle' : 'Miss', 
                'Ms' : 'Miss', 
                'Miss':'Miss',
                'Mme' : 'Mrs',
                'Mrs': 'Mrs'}

dfs = []
for dataset in allData:
    dataset['Title' ] = dataset['Title' ].map(commonTitles).fillna('Rare')
    dfs.append(dataset)
```